# How to fix can't connect to hdfs in spark-shell?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

i try to use spark-shell to connect hdfs

i use spark 2.4.3、scala 2.11.12、Hadoop 3.1.2

code in spark-shell

```
scala> val rdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp/1.json")
```

configuration in hadoop's core-site.xml file

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp</value>
        <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I also can get file in shell

```
 gary@localhost hadoop fs -cat "hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp/1.json"
2019-09-12 10:19:45,021 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
{"app":"优土","mac":"C3E302F6B285DA6BA955AA4996E9E568"}%
```

but fail in spark-shell

```
scala> val rdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp/1.json")
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp/1.json MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> rdd.count()
java.net.ConnectException: Call From localhost/127.0.0.1 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Comment: What if you read the file from `/tmp/1.json` not `hdfs://...`?

Comment: Do you run the spark session locally or in cluster mode? Have you tried `hdfs://<hostname>:8020/tmp/1.json` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: @Lamanus same issue.

Comment: i get it. when remove localhost config in /et/hosts, it works.